# How to display seller portfolio in seller product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, magento-community

How can I display seller info with short description on it's product page with a link of "View More Info". On click, the user can get redirect to the seller profile page. This would really help me out guys! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say an ideal solution would be to create an extension with a new "seller" entity type, then have an attribute on products linking to the seller entities. You could then build a new page based on the seller data and automatically link to it from product pages. Depending on your level of Magento knowledge (and available time) this could be quite a task.

An alternative approach could be to create a CMS page for each seller and then add an attribute to products linking to that CMS page. Its not as elegant but would be much faster

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I feel second option seems better as it's less of hassle. But if in case there are >100 seller then it could be quite hectic. Are you aware of any extension which can help in displaying seller profile in product page?

Comment: also, right now I have created a Tab for Seller Profile. Under which I'm able to add multiple sellers profile. Is there a possibility that the list of seller name can come as a dropdown at "manage Product" section. So, while adding a Product one can choose the seller and the short description of the seller can be displayed on product page?

Comment: You mean a select attribute to choose the seller of a product? You could do that by creating a product attribute with a custom source model. I would say that would be better suited to option A though as you would have to load the seller values from somewhere to display in the select, you couldn't really do that with cms pages.

Comment: How can we display SKU in URL structure? e.g domain/Product name kws/industry/SKU-product type. I'm also using SKU auto generator to generate SKU's.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you'd need to create [custom product attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields) and alter the design so that they were encapsulated into one area that you want them to be located in or one tab. And some information on adding custom tabs to a product page can be found on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470217/how-can-i-add-a-new-tab-in-product-page-in-magento).

After that you just need to customize the CSS of the theme to display it how you want, then create the page somehow for the seller profile. Either static pages, or possibly some blog system to accomplish that part.

Comment: Thanks chaoticgeek, Right now I have created a Tab for Seller Profile. Under which I'm able to add multiple sellers profile. Is there a possibility that the list of seller name can come as a dropdown at "manage Product" section. So, while adding a Product one can choose the seller and the short description of the seller can be displayed on product page?

Comment: You could do something like I've done in the past. Have the drop down for the products that you run a switch statement over and it selects the correct static block that it inserts then. It adds a bit more cruft to the product page though so you may or may not want to go that way depending on your page setup I'd guess.

Comment: How can we display SKU in URL structure? e.g domain/Product name kws/industry/SKU-product type. I'm also using SKU auto generator to generate SKU's.